# Alternatives to iisNode for my Express.js app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, iis, iisnode

I've ran into a rather interesting and unique situation regarding my current web application.

As of right now, I have a React front end, with a PHP backend that sends MSSQL data to the React front end. React sends requests using axios, and PHP retrieves said requests.

As of right now, the project works fine. HOWEVER, I do want to get express.js or Flask up and running for the project. React + PHP is not ideal, and it is EXTREMELY slow compared to when I was using express during my development stages.

The manager/administrator requests that the site not be listed on the sites of the IIS server. As a result, I cannot use things such as URL Rewrite to redirect URL requests to the express or Flask script.

My question is, is there anyway to URL rewrite without having the website listed in IIS? I've tried using iisNode to no avail, and I have been suggested running the server.js file in the background. Any help would be great!